# How to use GeoFencing package to update phones Profile?

Tags: android, geofencing

I want to build an app that changes the phone's profile to General, Vibrate or Silent when the user enters a custom-user set location. Im right now clueless on how to use the class. I tried the tutorials but couldnt understand.

When I try adding LocationServices the intelligence doesnt return anything...im stuck right now. Any kind of pointers or help would be appreciated.!!!

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors or exceptions have you encountered?

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple and detailed implementation of the [Geofence class](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/implementing-map-and-geofence-features-in-android-business-apps). This is the main [explanation about the Geofence](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) and it's implementation basic concepts. 
This is also another good example by Joe Howard. I highly recommend you read the docs first to get a basic understanding first. Then read the examples to see how other people used it to fit their needs; then you use the class according your needs.